# Building an intranet like page with Play framework

Tags: apache, playframework, owncloud, roundcube

Let's say I'm running a dedicated server with owncloud and roundcube on it. First idea was to protect those URLs with some kind of reverse proxy. However I would like to make it more secured and implement a two factor authentication.

The idea is to redirect clients to a login page (implemented with Play Framework), once user is authenticated, he is free to use owncloud or roundcube.

I have been thinking about this problem for a while now, here are my thoughts:

- Use play router to filter protected pages
- redirect to login page built with play
- [possible solution : once authenticated, redirect requests to internal web server running on a different port that can not be accessed from outside]

The main challenge is that owncloud is a PHP app running on apache, I need some magic to talk with the apache server (running play with apache as front-end is not excluded). This solution needs to be somewhat generic so that it can be used for other apps in the future.

I hope my idea is all clear, we can see this configuration as a private backend (with applications running in different environments) for a blog.

Question is, do you think this is the best way to go considering how play works and the configuration I want to implement ?

Thanks !

Comment: Sounds great. Go for it! (or did you have any question ?)

Comment: Well I just want to know if someone thinks this is not the best way to go. Thanks for giving your point of view.

Comment: Sorry, actually I tried to point out that you did not ask any question at all. You describe some project. But you did not ask any question. Remember: you will only get an answer if you ask a specific question. Do you want to get an answer?